# Alternative to thread.sleep() - amazon selenium webdriver add to cart ignore insurance dialog

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I am trying to avoid using Thread.sleep() but without it, No Thanks button on insurance dialog doesn't get clicked

Steps:

1. Search product on amazon.com
2. Click on product title
3. On product details click on add to cart
4. Click on No thanks button on buy insurance dialog
5. Item gets added to cart.

I have tried following to replace thread.sleep();

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("add-to-cart-button"))).click();
 try {
         Thread.sleep(2000);
            if (insurancePopUpDialog.isDisplayed()) {

                    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(insuranceNoThanksButton));

                  new Actions(driver).moveToElement(insuranceNoThanksButton).click().build().perform(); 
                  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.or(
                            ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"huc-v2-order-row-items-msg\"]")),
                            ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"huc-v2-order-row-confirm-text\"]")),
                            ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"attachDisplayAddBaseAlert\"]/div/h4"))

                    )); 
              }
        }   catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Tried implicit wait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid passing pre-declared WebElement to ExpectedConditions function as it should be readily available for WebDriver on browser. Try below inside if condition:-

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(<xpath for weblement insuranceNoThanksButton >)));
```

Later, you can declare  WebElement insuranceNoThanksButton for further operations.

If above doesn't work, try with javascript click:-

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", insuranceNoThanksButton);
```

Comment: Thanks Vishal for the prompt help. First option works. Thanks a lot for explaining in detail.

Comment: @jkk26 - Please upvote the answer in case it solved your question